# How to check if my Bool value is true in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

im using unity 2018 and using c#
i want to check if my bool value is true. this is
my code:

```
public class ShopButtonClick : MonoBehaviour 
{
    bool shopOpened = false;
    public GameObject upgradeOne;

    public void ClickTheButton()
    {
        if (shopOpened)
        {
            shopOpened = false;
            upgradeOne.SetActive(false);
        }
        else

        shopOpened = true;
        upgradeOne.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

the problem is that it doesnt work, i added the script to the button and it wont work, on my other project it works ok... but for some reason not now.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: you are doing exactly that wih if (shopOpened) ..  You might want some brackets around that else mind...

Comment: This question would have been a good question if instead of "*it doesn't work*" you wrote "*I don't understand why `upgradeOne` stays active regardless the amount of times I click the button*" - which is the expected behaviour of your code (because `upgradeOne.SetActive(true)` is executed everytime).

Answer (score 7):

You are missing brackets:

```
if (shopOpened)
{
    shopOpened = false;
    upgradeOne.SetActive(false);
}
// without brackets the else only applies to the first line of code after it
else
    shopOpened = true;

// This is always executed
upgradeOne.SetActive(true);
```

What you want is probably

```
if (shopOpened)
{
    shopOpened = false;
    upgradeOne.SetActive(false);
}
else
{
    shopOpened = true;
    upgradeOne.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

In fact I would rather write it simply as

```
public void ClickTheButton()
{
    // invert the bool flag
    shopOpened = !shopOpened;
    // directly re-use its value
    upgradeOne.SetActive(shopOpened);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a curly bracket after `else`.

While you can write an if/else statement without brackets only the first line after `else` will be treated as belongig to the else statement.
In your case that means `upgradeOne.SetActive(true);` will always be exexuted because it will be interpreted as.

```
if (shopOpened)
    {

        shopOpened = false;
        upgradeOne.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        shopOpened = true;
    }

    upgradeOne.SetActive(true);
```

I would always add brackets to exactly prevent this kind of bugs.